# How can I control the number of decimal places in rand function in fortran?

Tags: floating-point, fortran, precision

In the following code I want to generate a random number that has two digits after the decimal point. For example, I want a random variable to give (0.26) instead of (0.26463).

This is my code:

```
PROGRAM alaki
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL :: RANDOMREAL
CALL RANDOM_SEED()
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(RANDOMREAL)
PRINT *, "random number= ", RANDOMREAL

END PROGRAM alaki
```

Comment: Why don't you just round the result to 2 decimal places?

Comment: I want to use the result of "randomreal" in the other function. I don't want to show result!

Comment: This is going to turn into a discussion about internal number representation and formatting, sooner or later.

Comment: It is not really clear what you actually want (if it is not the rounding). Then you should perhaps explain what you are going to do with that number afterwards (i.e. why it has to have two decimal places).

Comment: @Joshua There is no base whatsover for the string-processing tag. Please read the comments. *"I want to use the result of "randomreal" in the other function. **I don't want to show result!** "*

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing as floating point numbers with two decimal places in Fortran. If you need to change the value you get from some function, you must round it yourself. You may want to create a function that wraps the original function.

The rounding may look like:

```
rounded = real(nint(randomreal * 100)) / 100
```

Comment: It is not correct because he's trying to print the number to two digits of significance, not round the number for further calculations.

Comment: @Joshua WHAT, I read *"I want to **generate** a random number that has two digits after the decimal point"*. The OP never said anything about printing and never clarified what he actually wants even after being asked to do that. And my answer is the thing to be downvoted?

Comment: @VladimirF: There are only 3 possible answers: 1) He needs to display a number with two digits after the decimal point sooner or later, 2) He needs to redo his algorithms to get a random _integer_ between 0 and 100, or 3) he needs to redo his algorithms to use fixed point numbers.

Comment: @Joshua You understand tha he wrote *I don't want to show result!* that this is Fortran and random integers are computd from floats by rounding and that it Fortran doesn't have any fixed point decimals, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
program alaki
    implicit none
    real :: randomreal, roundedrandomreal
    integer :: i
    character(*), parameter :: fmt = "(a,i2,a,g0,a,g0)"

    call random_seed()
    do i = 1, 10
        call random_number(randomreal)
        roundedrandomreal = nint(randomreal * 100) / 100.0
        write(*, fmt) "[", i, "]: ", randomreal, " -> ", roundedrandomreal
    end do
end
```

This is a posible output with a recent gfortran:

```
[ 1]: 0.228682280 -> 0.230000004
[ 2]: 0.765717089 -> 0.769999981
[ 3]: 0.183222830 -> 0.180000007
[ 4]: 0.144763827 -> 0.140000001
[ 5]: 0.710479259 -> 0.709999979
[ 6]: 0.108196735 -> 0.109999999
[ 7]: 0.802814901 -> 0.800000012
[ 8]: 0.873218477 -> 0.870000005
[ 9]: 0.833641887 -> 0.829999983
[10]: 0.522882819 -> 0.519999981
```

You can note that, even after those calculations, you **won't** get a number perfectly represented with all-zeroes on the right, just because the machine representation of decimal numbers is always an approximation (and that is the reason I, without knowing the logic of your subsequent calculation, can't see much sense in what you are trying to do). If you want better precision, you can change the kind-parameter of your real type.

Comment: OK, I think I should undelete my downvoted answer to warn you before @Joshua comes again.

Comment: omg, this is embarassing... still, this is clearly a XY problem and idek what OP is trying to achieve. This is the only reasonable answer, given the info shared.